# Reading the non delimited file with no particular patterns in the data

Tags: r

I want to read a ASCII file to R environment. However, the ASCII file is a non delimited and the data is not continuous (have some blank spaces between the variables) so in order to read the data i have used the below syntax i.e

```
test <- read.fwf("D:/R_process/ASCII.txt", width = c(10, 4, 1, 4, 9, 9, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,8))
```

Now I am able to read it but the data read is wrong. Actually, my out put should have only the applicable variables data but not the blank data. Below is the ASCII data. Please let me know how should i write the syntax to read only the applicable data in the file.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Here is the Data:

```
000000000120151  04 0.766696           1                         1000000000 010

000000000220151  04 1.458186           1                         1000100000 020

000000000320151  04 0.185492           1                         1000000000 015

000000000420151  04 0.961584           1                         1000000000 003

000000000520151  04 0.650091           2                         0001000000    

000000000620151  04 0.430350           1                         1000000000 020

000000000720151  04 3.192895           2                         1011000000 000

000000000820151  04 0.617127           1                         1010100000 015

000000000920151  04 0.399207           1                         1000000000 010
```

Comment: Probably i was not clear in my earlier explanation i hope so...In general if i am reading to SPSS environment i use the variable start and end position of the columns to read the particular variable so i SPSS code would be        SERIAL 1-10
YEAR 11-14
WAVE 15
CNTR 16-19
WEI 20-28
SMK 40
Brand1 71
Brand1 72
Brand1 73
Brand1 74
Brand1 75
Brand1 80
ABC 82-84
Main 101-108.. now i want to read the same to R i.e. only the applicable column/variable data no need of the blank data.

Comment: I thought my answer would read the data ignoring the blank data, doesn't it? Could you provide an example output?

Comment: @Jagadish does `strip.white` not do what you want? You could also use negative numbers in the width to skip columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
read.table("D:/R_process/ASCII.txt", sep = " ")
```

**EDIT** 
After @Nick K comment below, new answer:

I understand you just have the wrong widths:

```
read.fwf("D:/R_process/ASCII.txt", width = c(10, 4, 1, 4, 9, 12, 35, 4))
```

Comment: This won't work for the OP's file - the numbers in the 4th column are actually to be read individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strip.white` parameter on `read.fwf`.

```
test <- read.fwf("D:/R_process/ASCII.txt",
  width = c(10, 4, 1, 4, 9, 9, rep(1, 8), 3, 8),
  strip.white = TRUE)
```